# Unable to debug servlet in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging, servlets

I have a small web application that takes input from user and passes control to servlet.The application is working fine but I am unable to debug the application

I gives error on pressing **F5 that catalina.jar has no source attachment.**

The Steps I followed are

```
  Right click on project->Debug as->Debug on server
```

I have confirmed presence of rt.jar file in the link but it didnt worked for me

[Attach java source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kdc6q.png)

Snapshot are as follows

before pressing F5
[image]

After pressing F5
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to attach the **source code** of your `tomcat`, here is a link where you can find them [source](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi)

After downloading the source, you click on Attach sources (see the second snapshot) and you point to the location where you saved the sources.

Comment: yes it worked.thks but another issue has cropped up I am trying to redirect to a page through request dispatcher but while debugging it says source cannot be found edit source lookup path

Comment: what is the class name that it can't find the source for it?